# How do I write a SQL Query to fetch data according to a specific format/ pattern of String?

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle11g

I need to write a SQL query to fetch data according to a specific format of String. I need to fetch those records where the LOC column of my query looks like the following:

```
Cx-xxx-Lx
Or
Cxx-xxx-Lx
Or
x-xxx-Lx
Or
xx-xxx-Lx
Or
xxxxxLx_x
Or
xxxxxLx_xx
Or
BxxxLLxxxx
Where :-
x is a number (0 to 9)
L is a letter (A to Z)
```

I have filtered the LOC column to fetch data where the length of the record is either 9 or 10. Although this is fetching correct data from the DB, this is not a correct way of doing so.

My current SQL:

```
select * from table
where length(LOC) in (9,10)
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Use `REGEXP_LIKE`.

Answer (score 3):

You can use regular expressions.  Something like:

```
where regexp_like(LOC, '^C?[0-9]{1,2}-[0-9]{3}-[A-Z][0-9]$') or
      regexp_like(LOC, '^[0-9]{5}[A-Z][0-9]_[0-9]{1,2}$') or
      regexp_like(LOC, '^B[0-9]{3}[A-Z]{2}[0-9]{4}$')
```

You can combine these into one regular expression using `|`.  I think it is easier to follow and debug as three separate expressions.